# Question on Geopandas Spatial Join nearest

Tags: gis, spatial, geopandas

I have two GeoDataFrames that I am attempting to join. Both have POINT geometry. I am using geopandas.buffer to create Points and polygon and then spatial join.

`gpd1` with `POLYGON` geometry with shape `(1791, 266)`

`gpd2` with `POINT` geometry with shape `(3808, 2)`

The `crs` for both is:

```
<Derived Projected CRS: ESRI:102003>
Name: USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- E[east]: Easting (metre)
- N[north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: United States (USA) - CONUS onshore - Alabama; Arizona; Arkansas; California; Colorado; Connecticut; Delaware; Florida; Georgia; Idaho; Illinois; Indiana; Iowa; Kansas; Kentucky; Louisiana; Maine; Maryland; Massachusetts; Michigan; Minnesota; Mississippi; Missouri; Montana; Nebraska; Nevada; New Hampshire; New Jersey; New Mexico; New York; North Carolina; North Dakota; Ohio; Oklahoma; Oregon; Pennsylvania; Rhode Island; South Carolina; South Dakota; Tennessee; Texas; Utah; Vermont; Virginia; Washington; West Virginia; Wisconsin; Wyoming.
- bounds: (-124.79, 24.41, -66.91, 49.38)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic
- method: Albers Equal Area
Datum: North American Datum 1983
- Ellipsoid: GRS 1980
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

I do the spatial join using [sjoin_nearest](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin_nearest.html)

```
df_join = gpd.sjoin_nearest(
                            gpd1, # polygon geometry
                            gpd2, # point geometry
                            how = 'left',
                            max_distance = 0.0001, # in metres
                            distance_col = "distances"
                           )
```

When I inspect the resulting DataFrame, I notice that points that are clustered around have exactly the same # of matches. I have also used different values of `max distance` from `100` to `0.0001` but it didn't make a difference.

A couple of questions:

1. Why doesn't changing the values of `max distance` not make a difference? And `distances` for most rows is `0`?
2. I'd like to inject some degree of randomness. Instead of joining on exactly the same number of nearest points, how do I join on a random sample of nearest points?

The problem is, for `Polygons` that are close or overlapping, the results from join is exactly the same, which is not what I am looking for. I realize `#2` is a bit open-ended and would appreciate any ideas on randomness.

Comment: I suspect the distances are `0` because the `Points` are within the `Polygon` geom.

Comment: Sjoin and sjoin nearest make at most one match for each element in each of the two dataframes. You can’t e.g. get all points in df2 within a tolerance of df1, including each point in df2 multiple times if they’re close to multiple points in df1. Instead if multiple points are near a geom, only the first match will be returned. If you want all matches for each row in df1 I think you’ll have to loop over each row.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I get multiple matches for `df1` (left table) likely because the geometry is `Polygon` and the `Points` from `df2` are within the `Polygon`. Acc. to the docs, `Results will include multiple output records for a single input record where there are multiple equidistant nearest or intersected neighbors.` I believe this is what's happening, I get multiple joins because `points` intersect with `polygon` geometry.

Comment: Ahh got it. So yeah it seems like you could buffer df1 to whatever distance you want to include and then group by the df1 elements and select as many random elements from df2 as you’d like using np.random.choice

Comment: @MichaelDelgado sounds about right. I was thinking the same, using `random.sample(df2.points, x)`. I am using `buffer` to create `polygon` geometry from `point`. I am not quite following your `group by` comment. Why would we `group by` `df1` elements?

Comment: If you want a certain number of random matches by df1 point?

Answer (score 0):

I'm juste a beginner in this field, but I think that using kd-trees (sklearn), you can specify the number of 'nearest neighbours' you get.